# Abstract service primitive

Tags: snmp, osi, rfc

In SNMP RFC documents, often the concept of abstract service primitive (ASP) is used. What is ASP in fact ? I think it is also used in ISO OSI.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Abstract Service Primitives are standards functions defined in [RFC 3412](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3412) for SNMP requests, responses, registration and similar.

Comment: Thanks for answer. What confuses me is that in ISO OSI (and in TTCN for example) there also exist ASPs, but as I understood, ASPs there are not functions but messages that traverse protocol stack (and contain PDUs).

Comment: That is quite possible. The term can be used in different ways. It's a bit like "PDU" which has a different meaning in each of the layer instances.